# Lacunary weight one modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

By a result of Serre, it’s known that a cusp form of weight $k\geq2$ and level $\Gamma_0(N)$ with some $\chi$ is lacunary if and only if it is in the space of CM newforms. Is there a similar result for the case of weight 1? Say, can we also characterize lacunary modular forms of weight 1 in terms of some special modular forms such as theta series? Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Serre proved in 1985 that weight 1 cusp forms are *always* lacunary; see Theorem 19 of Serre's article

*Serre, Jean-Pierre*, [**Quelques applications du théorème de densité de Chebotarev**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02698692), Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 54, 123-202 (1981). [ZBL0496.12011](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0496.12011).

in which he proves that for any weight 1 cusp form $f$, we have $$\#\{ n \le X : a_n(f) \ne 0\} = O(X / (\log x)^{1/4}).$$

Certain special weight 1 forms satisfy estimates of the above form with powers of log larger than $1/4$; the largest possible exponent is $3/4$. In contrast, weight $\ge 2$ CM forms satisfy an analogous estimate with exponent $1/2$, so these special weight 1 forms are in a sense strictly *more* lacunary than any form of weight $\ge 2$.

Comment: Thanks so very much, David, for your response and explanation! I have a subsequent question that what about holomorphic modular forms of weight 1, not necessarily cuspidal. Is it still true that any holomorphic modular form of weight 1 is lacunary?

Comment: Yes, I think it is still true. Try to prove it for an Eisenstein eigenfrom (where the Galois rep is isomorphic to the direct sum of two characters).

Comment: Thank you, David, for your help!